# regex to select 2nd option from group value (a|b)

Tags: regex, if-statement

my regex i wrote is `(a|b)-(?(1)(1)|(2))` what it is supposed to do:

if `a` then `a-1` allowed

if `b` then `b-2` allowed

having **group 1 = a or b** and **group 2 = 1 or 2**

i have tried using `((?'a'a)|b)-(?(a)(1)|(2))` but it gave me different groups for numbers being **group 3 or 4**

how can i keep numbers group to **2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [zero-width positive lookahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) non-capturing group.

`(a(?=-1)|b(?=-2))-(1|2)`

Matches `a` only if `a` is followed by `-1`.
Matches `b` only if `b` is followed by `-2`.
Then match a `-`, and a `1` or a `2`.
Capture group 1 is `a` or `b`.
Capture group 2 is `1` or `2`.

Comment: can it check for number only without `-` sign if it is exist in lookahead or any method to check if a number occured once ahead or lookbehind?

Comment: @MarkElvis Anything inside the `(?=xxx)` zero-width positive lookahead is regex too, so it can match whatever you can make a regex match.

Comment: tried something like (a|b)-((?<=^a.+)1|2) but i think i wrote it wrong I want to use lookbehind because all my regex depends on result before it and some regexs are 70 characters long